# How do I trigger a JavaScript function when a button is pressed in HTML code

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am trying to create a calculator that solves the Pythagoras theorem. I have created a function inside a  tag in my code which takes two arguments (one for each leg length of the right-angled triangle) The function works if I just do a console.log with two numbers as arguments and the function executes properly if it is inside the script tag. But I just want to know how to take the two arguments in the text boxes and then when I press the button make the result appear on the screen.

```
<html>
  <main>
    <head>
        <!--Textboxes to input lengths of legs-->

        <input type = "text" required placeholder= "1st legnth">
        <br> <br>
        <input type = "text" required placeholder= "2nd legnth">
        <br> <br>
        <button type = "submit">Give me the answer.
    </head>
   </main>
</html>


 <script>


    function solveforHyp (a, b)
    {

     var c = a*a + b*b;

     return Math.sqrt(c);

     }

     var final = (solveforHyp(3, 4));

     console.log(final);

     </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

add a span after the button to contain the final result:

```
<span id="final-result"></span>
```

add an onclick event to your button, it might look like this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="onButtonSubmit()"></button>
```

you might also give some relevant ID's to the input like this:

```
<input type = "text" id="first-length" required placeholder= "1st legnth">
<input type = "text" id="second-length" required placeholder= "2nd legnth">
```

and finally, write the onButtonSubmit function to access the inputs and call the solveforHyp function :

```
function onButtonSubmit(){
     const firstValue = document.getElementById('first-length').value;
     const secondValue = document.getElementById('second-length').value;

     document.getElementById('final-result').innerText = solveforHyp(firstValue,secondValue); // finally, put the returned value in the created span.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your document structure is entirely wrong, a lot of tags are not closed script is after the HTML tag, and content is written inside head tag and head is inside main, NO doctype declaration is done, and most importantly if you wanna submit something you should have a form at least with preventing its default behavior. Learn HTML before JavaScript Brother, and also its a good practice to use input type Number when you already know the input will be always a Number.

and here is the code what you are trying to make

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <form id="formOne">
            <input type="number" required placeholder="1st legnth" id="first">
            <br> <br>
            <input type="number" required placeholder="2nd legnth" id="second">
            <br> <br>
            <button type="submit">Give me the answer</button>
    </form>
</body>

<script>
    let form = document.querySelector("#formOne");
    let inputOne = document.querySelector("#first");
    let inputTwo = document.querySelector("#second");

    form.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(inputOne.value,2) + Math.pow(inputTwo.value,2)));
    })

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Js file function to be called

```
function tryMe(arg) {
    document.write(arg);
}
```

HTML FILE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='object.js'> </script>
    <title>abc</title><meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    tryMe('This is me vishal bhasin signing in');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try like this:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="form">
      <input type="text" id="first_length" name="first_length" />
      <input type="text" id="second_length" name="second_length" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

    <script>
      function logSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var first_length = document.getElementById("first_length").value;
        var second_length = document.getElementById("second_length").value;

        var final = solveforHyp(first_length, second_length);

        console.log(final);
      }

      const form = document.getElementById("form");

      form.addEventListener("submit", logSubmit);

      function solveforHyp(a, b) {
        var c = a * a + b * b;

        return Math.sqrt(c);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```